#  How do I select context menu template dynamically based on runtime property value in XAML? (context menu customization)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, customization

There are two context menus. To open the needed the context menu click the right mouse button. If IsData is true, ContextMenu1 will open; if IsData is false, ContextMenu2 will open. The issue will be unfolded in XAML.

There are two static context menu in DataTemplate. How does one context menu use them?
This block sets the template context menu entirely. Which is chosen, depending on conditions.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContextMenuControlTemplate">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>

        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuSet">
            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="15" Height="15" Source="{DynamicResource img_icon}"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="  Add item" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </MenuItem.Header>
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="True"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Remove"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>

        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuDel">
            <MenuItem Header=" Del all"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>

    </DataTemplate.Resources>

    <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenuForItems"/>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.IsData}" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="contextMenuForItems" Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenuSet}" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.IsData}" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="contextMenuForItems" Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenuDel}" />
        </DataTrigger>

    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here block is trying to use our established a context menu. A problem is in this it.

```
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Data.IsData}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContextMenuControlTemplate}"
                                     />
                                </DataTemplate>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: wait, what? what are you talking about? what exactly doesn't work? what platform is this based upon? ...please read the faq, before asking questions.

Comment: check the new edition, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used workaround. I make one complex menu. And some missing MenuItem are deleted. See keywords Visibility and booleanToVisibilityConverter. My example is below.

```
                                <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem IsEnabled="False" Visibility="{Binding Data.IsData, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter2}}">
                                            <MenuItem.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Image Width="15" Height="15" Source="{DynamicResource img_icon}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="  Add item" />

                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </MenuItem.Header>
                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <RadioButton IsChecked="True"/>
                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click"  Header="Remove" Visibility="{Binding Data.IsData, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter2}}" />
                                        <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Del all" Visibility="{Binding Data.IsData, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter2}, ConverterParameter=InvertCollapse}" />
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
```

And booleanToVisibilityConverter2 is wrapper for BooleanToVisibilityConverter, which it has additional properties.